# How to prevent session keep alives

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a customer whose website uses authentication for logged in users. The user sessions have a timeout of 30 minutes, after which they are logged out. Several pages periodically poll data from the server.

The issue I have is that logged in users never have their session expire as there is a constant connection with the server due to the background polling. Is there a way to prevent connections to certain addresses from resetting the session timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a request received to the server, the session will be updated and session will never be expired as you stated. You can make a workaround as below. Copy the code to Global.asax.

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        DateTime? userLastActive = (DateTime?)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLastActive"];
        if (userLastActive.HasValue && DateTime.Now.Subtract(userLastActive.Value).Minutes > 15)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            return;
        }

        // Check if the request for background tasks
        var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        var action = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        if (controller == "BackGroundTaskController" &&
            action == "BackGroundTaskAction")
        {
            // ignore
            return;
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLastActive"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

At each request the code below will be executed. You can set the variable "UserLastActive" to session object except for the periodical requests. You can then check for the last active time of the user and make the session end.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Whilst this solution you gave does work I actually found another solution that involves deleting the cookie part of any reponse. Essentially preventing the cookie from updating its time. I still have to test it. https://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/asp-net-mvc-avoid-resetting-the-form-authentication-cookie-timeout-for-a-request/